# Android setThumb(drawable) variable type?

Tags: android, drawable, seekbar

All,

I'm trying to dynamically change the image displayed on the thumb of the seekbar in java, and came across the setThumb method. I have a .png file under res/drawable, but can't find the right way to refer to that .png file using setThumb(). Do any of you know how to do it?

Best and Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a drawable from your resource.

```
Drawable mypicture= getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mypicture);
```